# How to get Netgear A6200 to work on 14.04

Tags: wireless

I bought the Netgear A6200 USB wireless adapter, and I used WINE to run the installer from the disk that came with the adapter, but it failed part way through.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: You might try the files at post #7 here: http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=79948

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu.  How do you use ndiswrapper to load .inf files?

Comment: Also, tried the method on post 7, but it still isn't working.  After I try it and type "ndiswrapper -l" is says "bcmwlhigh5 : driver installed"  But....when I plug in the USB adapter, it doesn't work.

Comment: So, after doing a little digging, I got it to work.  You do get far enough in the install using WINE for this to work properly.  Here are the steps:

1.  Open the shell, and type in **cd .wine**
2.  **cd drive_c**
3.  **cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/**
4.  **cd NETGEAR**
5.  **cd A6200**
6.  **cd Drivers**
7.  **sudo diswrapper -i** *nameoffile* **.inf**
8.  **sudo modprobe diswrapper**
9.  **sudo ndiswrapper -m** 

And that got it to work.

***Note:*** The adapter did NOT work until after the command **sudo modprobe diswrapper**

Comment: Glad it's working! Great job.

Comment: I followed your steps exactly and everything seems to work, but when I enter the correct password (I've checked and retyped it like 50 times) it still won't let me connect to the network.  Just keeps popping up the "Authentication required by wireless network" dialogue.  Seems odd.

Answer (score 3):

With Ubuntu 14.04 I did the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
wget www.mediafire.com/?od9wpw6ccrnyhaa
unzip A6200_Linux_drivers.zip
sudo ndisgtk
```

Then when ndisgtk is running, choose the file ending in "ing" that was unzipped. It should be bcmwlhigh5.inf. Once that is installed you can select a wifi network from the Network menu-bar item.

Comment: wget didn't work... had to go to the link directly in a browser

Comment: I also don't know how to confirm that it's working, and that I'm not using my internal wifi card

Answer (score 1):

Solved with https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210 - **plug your device out** before the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

**If your device was plugged in before the above steps**, unplug and re-attach, the OS will detect and you should see available Wifi hotspots

Answer (score 0):

The solutions I found, including the ones given here, did not work for me unfortunately. Seems to be some issues with newer kernels.

However, I just found out what works for me. The following github repository contains many non-free and proprietary modules including one for the mt7662 chipset which is used in the Netgear A6200/A6210.

Had to simply clone the repository in */lib/modules/* and *modprobe mt76-usb* and she now works like a charm. Hope this helps those who also had trouble overlooking this simple option.

See https://github.com/NXP/linux-firmware