# Netgear USB wifi adapter driver for Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, netgear

I recently switched over from windows 8 to Ubuntu and the installation process went by really smoothly. Once everything was complete, I came across one small problem in terms of wifi connection. I have a MSI Z77 MPower and it has wifi detection built in; and it's terrible. Weak wifi so my solution was to get a Netgear USB wifi adapter.

When it comes to Ubuntu, I'm not able to install the driver for Ubuntu to detect the Netgear adapter. The built in wifi detector on my mobo is too weak to even load a webpage, leaving me with no internet connection for Ubuntu.
Is there any way for me to get the driver through windows 8 and transfer it to Ubuntu via USB or any way to extend the wifi detection capabilities of my MSI motherboard?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I've added the output of `lsusb` please let me know how to proceed next. I'm totally stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website might help
http://grephaxs.com/best-usb-wifi-adapter-for-linux/ 
According to grephaxs Alfa is the best
USB adapter for Linux .
It is plug n play and compatible with Windows operating system

Answer (score 1):

Netgear Wifi USB, this is a bit vague. Please identify the USB model # and revision #

and yes you can import the driver into Ubuntu using ndis-wrapper, but this requires that the driver package includes the .inf file.

Look for:

> With Ubuntu 14.04 I did the following steps

This post should help getting the driver and show you how to get ndis-wrapper working [Install Windows driver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460277/how-to-get-netgear-a6200-to-work-on-14-04)

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to include that;  I have a netgear USB A6200 Wifi adapter

Comment: I just updated my the link to solve your riddle. Please post your results

Comment: Why do you suggest ndiswrapper? Are you sure there are no linux drivers? Ndiswrapper is obsolete.

Comment: Visited the Netgear website, surprise no Linux support, checked more forums to see if anyone has made one, I found none. The link I inserted shows the use of ndisgtk.

Comment: Everything works fine up until unzip A6200_LInux_Drivers.zip. http://i.imgur.com/CtEHqdr.png. I downloaded the program from mediafire. Here's a screenshot of the entire process: http://i.imgur.com/wt4tmXP.png

Comment: Ok their wget link was not valied - this will work: wget http://download2173.mediafire.com/71613yyh5wwg/od9wpw6ccrnyhaa/A6200_Linux_Drivers.zip

Comment: Have you had any luck yet? Your results can help others