# Netgear N-300/ WNA3100 USB Adapter for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet, netgear

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and I am having trouble connecting to the Internet.

I have a netgear WNA3100 USB Adapter and I don't have anything in my additional drivers.

Comment: See also the official page for `ndiswrapper`: http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNA3100

Answer (score 4):

You can add Support for the `Netgear N-300/ WNA3100 USB Adapter` by installing the `ndiswrapper` and loading the Windows network driver.

**Install the ndiswrapper modules**

```
$ sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common
$ sudo apt-get install  ndiswrapper-source ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

**Activate the ndiswrapper:**

```
$ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

**Load the driver into the ndiswrapper:**

Navigate to where you saved the driver (look at the `Download Windows Netgear Drivers` section below):

```
$ sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmwlhigh5.inf
(Add the ndiswrapper modules to the boot configuration with:)
$ sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

**Download the Windows Netgear Drivers**

You can download the driver from [NetGear Site: WNA3100 Drivers](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19878/~/wna3100-software-version-2.0?cid=wmt_netgear_organic).  The only thing you need from the download package is the `WNA3100` folder.

The exptracted `WNA3100` folder is available at:
http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/networksupport/

---

**Note:**
*You only need `wine` for extracting the `WNA3100.zip` package from the `setup.exe` file from the Netgear site.  After running `setup.exe` you'll find the zip package in:*

```
~/".wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/NETGEAR"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47173/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-netgear-n-300-wna3100-usb-adapter-for-ubunt).  Please continue your discussion/troubleshooting there.  Thank you!

Comment: **Note for readers**: if you ended up using ndiswrapper because GNU/Linux driver still not supplied, please consider [complaining to Netgear support](http://www.netgear.com/support/) about it. Because if everybody silently gets away with the workaround, how can a company know if there's demand.

Comment: Just tried ndiswrapper. It doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone help?

Comment: the output of `modprobe` on 20.04 is: `FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-43-generic`. Do you have any suggestion? Apparently package `ndiswrapper-utils` does not exist anymore and `ndiswrapper` is selected instead by `apt` if you try to install it.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not delete this post even if its not an answer. I am convinced that it will help a lot of users.

I just want to share my experience (especially for users who do not have a usb wifi dongle and want to buy one).

I just had the worst experience ever. After each kernel update it wan't working and i had to use a lot of complicated commands to make it work. Internet gives 1000 different solution and only some of them may work (after spending hours and hours). And when I restart or put my pc on sleep the wifi connection was never automatic. I had to turn it of and on again! such a pain

In order to avoid such a headache I just bought a WiFi PCIe card (a tp-link ac1900. I guess other PCIe card also works well but I haven't tried them. I just put that card inside my computer then i opened the additional driver menu and enabled the propriatary driver broadcom. Now my card works like a charm. I lost a bit money because I bought the usb wifi for nothing but I am much more happy to save my time and have a pleasant linux user experience.

Besides that there is many different size of PCI slots. Usually the wireless pcie cards have the size x1. My pc does not have x1, but i put the card in a x16 pcie slot and now it's fully compatible.

I know I do not answer to the question directely. But I hope that my post will be usefull for some users.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the same wifi adapter for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 it worked fine for me. If you have a lan connection do an update.

`sudo apt-get update`

Make sure that networking is enabled and try to connect manually from the network wizard.

Check the following guide to install the Windows driver in Ubuntu

[How to get Netgear A6200 to work on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460277/how-to-get-netgear-a6200-to-work-on-14-04)

Supported usb adapters by Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsNetgear#USB

Comment: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs