# ndiswrapper and WINE for ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, 19.10, education

I'm looking for the programs ndiswrapper and WINE by using the Ubuntu Software tool on ubuntu 19.10, but they are not present. Where I can find them?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Both packages are present in the repos. Beware that `ndiswrapper` is obsolete and practically useless in 99% of cases.

Comment: Hello @Pilot6, what is repos? I need them because i want to install the netgear wifi adapter wna3100

Comment: Repos = repositories. It is completely wrong way to install drivers this way. It won't work. You better search for wna3100 solutions or ask a new question. This is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6 I found a solution about ubuntu 16.04, can i ask the same question for ubuntu 19.10? https://askubuntu.com/questions/839947/netgear-n-300-wna3100-usb-adapter-for-ubuntu-16-04#

Comment: This solution should work for 19.10.

Comment: I agree with @Pilot6 ndiswrapper is not the way to go. WINE is pretty useless IMHO also.

Comment: @Pilot6 OPs linked solution also uses ndiswrapper.

Comment: Redo your question and ask about the real solution that you're asking for... how to make the Netgear wifi adapter wna3100 work with 19.10.

Comment: Well `ndiswrapper` is the last resort when nothing else works and WinXP drivers are still available.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the precoius suggestions.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you write the links of the installation files of ndiswrapper and wine please?

Comment: That solution contains installation of `ndiswraper`. Wine is installed by `sudo apt install wine`.