# Installing Netgear N300 wifi adapter WNA3100 on Ubuntu 19.10 without using ndiswrapper

Tags: wireless, software-installation, 19.10, adapter, education

I'm looking for a way to install the Netgear N300 wifi adapter WNA3100 on Ubuntu 19.10. Can you tell me how to do that please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you found a solution for Ubuntu 16.04. Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/839947/netgear-n-300-wna3100-usb-adapter-for-ubuntu-16-04#

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 I modified my question.

Comment: I am afraid `ndiswrapper` is the only available solution for this device, because there are no linux drivers at all. It is a poor solution, but there is no other.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use it. Thank you @Pilot6